# type 'BasedPersonVO' is not a subtype of type 'PersonVO' in type cast Hive Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am new to flutter.I have encounter the problem while using hive.
Super class is not a subtype of extended class.
Here is my two classes and error occur when i retrieve PersonVO from hive.

I already re-register adapter and check generated file.And I don't know why the problem still persist.

```
    The following _CastError was thrown building Builder:
type 'BasedPersonVO' is not a subtype of type 'PersonVO' in type cast

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///home/thurain/FlutterProjects/movie_app/lib/main.dart:46:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Keystore.getValues.<anonymous closure> (package:hive/src/box/keystore.dart:124:45)
#1      MappedIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:389:20)
#2      new _GrowableList._ofOther (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:198:26)
#3      new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:152:26)
#4      new List.of (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:50:28)
```

Here is my based class BasePersonVO class

```
part 'based_person_vo.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: HIVE_TYPE_ID_BASED_PERSON_VO,adapterName: 'BasedPersonVOAdapter')
@JsonSerializable()
class BasedPersonVO{
  @HiveField(0)
  @JsonKey(name: 'name')
  String name;

  @HiveField(1)
  @JsonKey(name: 'profile_path')
  String profilePath;


  BasedPersonVO(this.name, this.profilePath);

  factory BasedPersonVO.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => _$BasedPersonVOFromJson(json);

  Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => _$BasedPersonVOToJson(this);
}
```

BasedPersonVO generated class

```
part of 'based_person_vo.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class BasedPersonVOAdapter extends TypeAdapter<BasedPersonVO> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 1;

  @override
  BasedPersonVO read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return BasedPersonVO(
      fields[0] as String,
      fields[1] as String,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, BasedPersonVO obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.name)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.profilePath);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is BasedPersonVOAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

BasedPersonVO _$BasedPersonVOFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return BasedPersonVO(
    json['name'] as String,
    json['profile_path'] as String,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$BasedPersonVOToJson(BasedPersonVO instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'name': instance.name,
      'profile_path': instance.profilePath,
    };
```

PersonVO class

```
part 'person_vo.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: HIVE_TYPE_ID_PERSON_VO, adapterName: 'PersonVOAdapter')
@JsonSerializable()
class PersonVO extends BasedPersonVO{

  @HiveField(2)
  @JsonKey(name: 'adult')
  bool adult;

  @HiveField(3)
  @JsonKey(name: 'gender')
  int gender;

  @HiveField(4)
  @JsonKey(name: 'id')
  int id;

  @HiveField(5)
  @JsonKey(name: 'known_for')
  List<KnownForVO> knownFor;

  // @JsonKey(name: 'name')
  // String name;
  //
  // @JsonKey(name: 'profile_path')
  // String profilePath;

  PersonVO(this.adult, this.gender, this.id, this.knownFor,String name,String profilePath) : super(name, profilePath);

  factory PersonVO.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$PersonVOFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonVOToJson(this);
}
```

PersonVO generated class

```
part of 'person_vo.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class PersonVOAdapter extends TypeAdapter<PersonVO> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 8;

  @override
  PersonVO read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return PersonVO(
      fields[2] as bool,
      fields[3] as int,
      fields[4] as int,
      (fields[5] as List)?.cast<KnownForVO>(),
      fields[0] as String,
      fields[1] as String,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, PersonVO obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(6)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.adult)
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..write(obj.gender)
      ..writeByte(4)
      ..write(obj.id)
      ..writeByte(5)
      ..write(obj.knownFor)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.name)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.profilePath);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is PersonVOAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

PersonVO _$PersonVOFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return PersonVO(
    json['adult'] as bool,
    json['gender'] as int,
    json['id'] as int,
    (json['known_for'] as List)
        ?.map((e) =>
            e == null ? null : KnownForVO.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        ?.toList(),
    json['name'] as String,
    json['profile_path'] as String,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$PersonVOToJson(PersonVO instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'name': instance.name,
      'profile_path': instance.profilePath,
      'adult': instance.adult,
      'gender': instance.gender,
      'id': instance.id,
      'known_for': instance.knownFor,
    };
```

PersonDao class
**Error occur here when i called getAllperson() method.**

```
class PersonDao{
  
  
  static final PersonDao _singleton = PersonDao._internal();
  
  factory PersonDao(){
    return _singleton;
  }
  
  
  PersonDao._internal();
  
  void saveAllPerson(List<PersonVO> personList) async {
    Map<int,PersonVO> personMap = Map.fromIterable(personList,key: (person) => person.id, value: (person) => person);
     await getPersonBox().putAll(personMap);
  }

  List<PersonVO> getAllPerson(){
    return getPersonBox().values.toList();
  }

  Box<PersonVO> getPersonBox(){
    return Hive.box<PersonVO>(BOX_NAME_PERSON_VO);
  }
  
}
```

Thanks for your time.